# How to write a JSON object to a .json file in S3, using Lambda(python)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

So, at one point in my Lambda function, I'm converting my data into a JSON object:

```
x=json.dumps(my_data)
```

Now, I want to store the object `x` as a .json file in S3. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Write-S3Object cmdlet supports the ability to upload in-line text content to Amazon S3. Using the -Content parameter (alias -Text), you can specify text-based content that should be uploaded to Amazon S3 without needing to place it into a file first. The parameter accepts simple one-line strings as well as here strings that contain multiple lines.

```
PS > # Specifying content in-line, single line text:
PS > write-s3object mybucket -key myobject.txt -content "file content"

PS > # Specifying content in-line, multi-line text: (note final newline needed to end in-line here-string)
PS > write-s3object mybucket -key myobject.txt -content @"
>> line 1
>> line 2
>> line 3
>> "@
>> 
PS > # Specifying content from a variable: (note final newline needed to end in-line here-string)
PS > $x = @"
>> line 1
>> line 2
>> line 3
>> "@
>> 
PS > write-s3object mybucket -key myobject.txt -content $x
```